# What does my coworker mean that our company doesn't support "Comp"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was talking to a coworker that said that our company doesn't support "Comp".

We were talking about taking overtime to complete a project this weekend.
I searched for comp in relation to jobs and work and only found references to "Workers Compensation" or "Workers Comp", which I'm pretty sure doesn't apply to this situation.

Is he just using "Comp" as a short way of saying "Compensation"?  And if he is, how does that apply?  The company does support compensation or we wouldn't be getting paid for our work.

Comment: How about *asking him*? We are total strangers who can only guess. He is your coworker who actually knows.

Comment: He left for the day.  Besides, from the FAQ: `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Comp time" is time off in *compensation* for extra hours worked. For example, you had to work 60 hours last week to get a project finished, so you get to take Friday off this week. (I never said it was fair or equable). It is common in Information Technology, where there are requirements for *sprints* and/or off-hour support.

Answer (score 3):

"Comp time" is compensatory time, as explained in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtime#Time_off_in_lieu) (and in many other online sources, if you google for compensatory time). The wikipedia entry says: "*Time off in lieu*; *compensatory time*; or *comp time* refers to a type of work schedule arrangement that allows (or requires) workers to take time off instead of, or in addition to, receiving overtime pay."  It then goes on to state it is "legal in the public sector but not in the private sector".  For example, the [U.S Office of Personnel Management](http://www.opm.gov/oca/pay/html/comp.htm) spells out in excruciating detail the comp-time rules for public sector workers.  The terms "non-exempt" and "exempt" refer respectively to workers subject to, or not subject to, U.S. wage and hour laws.  Typically, private sector hourly workers are non-exempt and required to take higher-rate overtime pay but not officially allowed to take comp time, while salaried workers are exempt, with comp time but not overtime pay available to them.

Comment: Illegal where? Might be worth saying.

Answer (score 0):

Comp is not just about paying for the extra hours an employee had put for the organisation. It also covers injuries or replacements of the employee that met with an accident while performing the task or duty. Employers usually buy "[Workers Compensation Insurance Coverage](http://brightstoneins.com/deliveryinsurance/programs/employee-benefits-insurance/workers-compensation)" to make sure that they can pay you for your extra efforts under any circumstances.