# Can one compensate down? Is that an appropriate use of the word compensate?

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of “compensate” as a recompense for gain instead of loss](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44292/usage-of-compensate-as-a-recompense-for-gain-instead-of-loss)

Can the word *compensate* be used to adjust downward, i.e., *compensate down*?

Comment: Can you add some context to your question?

Comment: If I am guessing the context (related to money) correctly, then the word you might want to use is "Adjustment".

Answer (score 1):

Compensate is counterbalancing, but in general means

> "Recompense (someone) for loss, suffering, or injury, typically by the
>   award of a sum of money."

If, we are talking in context of money, where an amount has to be "taken back" then **Adjustment** would serve the purpose

Answer (score 1):

According to etymonline, *[compensation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=compensation&allowed_in_frame=0)* derives from Latin meaning "a weighing one thing against another, a balancing", so that in itself, *[compensate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=compensate&searchmode=none)* need not imply either "upward" or "downward".  Example: "We adjusted the rudder to compensate for side winds".  Sentences like "He was compensated for his time" exhibit a different usage of *compensated*, equivalent to *[recompensed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recompense#Verb)*, a word mentioned in previous answer.

You may also find a [question about comp time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43081/what-does-my-coworker-mean-that-our-company-doesnt-support-comp) of interest.

Answer (score 0):

More common use would probably be *handicap* - so you compensate a faster horse by adding extra weight to handicap it and produce a closer race.